# ffmpeg reduce memory consumption

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, rtsp

I'm developing an application, capturing some ip camera with RTSP protocols and send them to one server.
everything is going well when the resolution of ip cameras is low but when they're increased the memory consumption of my program goes up suddenly.

I've realized that ffmpeg stores a sequence of frames which we can seek to. 
1.is there any way to reduce the len of that?

2.is it possible to reduce the frame size when the ffmpeg reads the frames from the input(=>ip camera)? the size 400x400 is enough for my app but currently it's 2048

3.or any other way to help me reduce memory usage

Answer (score 0):

1) **To reduce memory** :

i) Reduce frame rate : use -framerate

ii) Increase compression by selecting longer GOP : use  -g

2) **To scale your input** : use -s switch

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -g 14 -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -s 400x400 http://localhost:1234/out.ffm
```

**Edited:**

For integrating ffmpeg to your c++ project, these are some of the solutions:

1. Using `system(ffmpeg command line);` // Easy
2. Use `CreatePrcess` and pipes to hide console window and show progress in your GUI. // Medium
3. Use ffmpeg distributed include files and libraries to integrate in your project. // Need high learning curve

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can I reduce frame rate in c++ code?

Comment: @EhsanVahab: Edited to include answer to your query in the  comment.